# override proxy restful service iOS

Tags: ios, rest, proxy, nsurlconnection

In our iOS app I am using NSURLConnection for invoking a web service. Our clients are using the the mobile app from their company wifi. But when they use the app from their company wifi, their proxy blocks the access to the web service. But when they use it from 3G, it works fine. Can you suggest a solution for this issue?

How I need to ignore/override the proxy while invoking a rest service. Or I need to set the proxy server and port number while invoking the service. Please advice.